# problem ajax load with autocomplete.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i created a jquery autocomplete it work true, but loading `LOADING...` it after removed value by `Backspace` don't work true. it not hide and Still is show.

how can after removed value by `Backspace`, hide `LOADING...` ?

**EXAMPLE:** [Please click on link and see problem](http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/tour_foreign/insert_foreign)

my full code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

/// LOADING... ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $('#loadingDiv')
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });

/// autocomplete /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////            
    $('.auto_complete').keyup(function () {
        var specific = '.' + $(this).closest('div.auto_box').find('b').attr('class');
        var cl_list = '.' + $(this).closest('div.auto_box').find('ul').attr('class');        
        var id = '#' + this.id;
        var url = $(id).attr('class');
        var dataObj = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: url,
            data: dataObj,
            cache: false,            
            success: function (data) {
                //alert(url)
                var cl_list = '.' + $('.auto_box '+ specific +' ul').attr('class');
                var id_name = $(cl_list).attr('id');
                $(cl_list).show().html('');
                if (data == 0) {
                    $(cl_list).show().html('<p><b>There is no</b></p>');
                }
                else {
                    $.each(data, function (a, b) {
                        //alert(b.name)
                        $('<p id="' + b.name + '">' + b.name + '</p>').appendTo(cl_list);
                    });

                    $(cl_list + ' p').click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var ac = $(this).attr('id');
                        $('<b>' + ac + 'ØŒ <input type="text" name="'+id_name+'[]" value="' + ac + '" style="border: none; display: none;" /></b>').appendTo($('.auto_box ' + specific + ' span'));
                        $(this).remove();
                        return false;
                    });
                    $('.auto_box span b').live('click', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(this).remove();
                        return false;
                    });
                }        
                if ($(specific + ' input').val() == '') {
                    $(cl_list + " p").hide().remove();
                    $(cl_list).css('display','none');
                    $(".list_name").show().html('');
                };
                $('body').click(function () {
                    $(cl_list + " p").hide().remove();
                    $('.auto_complete').val('');
                    $(cl_list).show().html('');
                    $(cl_list).css('display','none')
                });
            },
            "error": function (x, y, z) {
                // callback to run if an error occurs
                alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i keep getting this error `document.getElementById("clock") is null`

Comment: problem `LOADING...` is not about problem `clock`. They are different.

Comment: Please check again. error `clock` is not but there is still problem `LOADING...`. !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use jsfiddle next time you post code examples in a link.

Nevermind. The "loading" message keeps there because there's no fallback to empty values on results.

A quick fix could be just by test that there's a value in the input before making any post like `if(this.value == ""){
   $(cl_list).css('display', 'none');
   return false;
 }`

[Here's how it works with it](http://jsfiddle.net/uLh9h/)